# Display image as grayscale

Tags: python, matplotlib, grayscale, imshow

I'm trying to display a grayscale image using `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()`.  My problem is that the grayscale image is displayed as a colormap.  I need it to be grayscale because I want to draw on top of the image with color.

I read in the image and convert to grayscale using PIL's `Image.open().convert("L")`

```
image = Image.open(file).convert("L")
```

Then I convert the image to a matrix so that I can easily do some image processing using

```
matrix = scipy.misc.fromimage(image, 0)
```

However, when I do

```
figure()  
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(matrix)  
show()
```

it displays the image using a colormap (i.e. it's not grayscale).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 503, accepted):

The following code will load an image from a file `image.png` and will display it as grayscale.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

fname = 'image.png'
image = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
arr = np.asarray(image)
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)
plt.show()
```

If you want to display the inverse grayscale, switch the cmap to `cmap='gray_r'`.

Comment: @jay: Per [this doc string](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), "Note that
any colormap listed here can be reversed by appending `_r`."

Comment: Warning matplotlib adjust pixel scale intensity if you do not want use:
`plt.imshow(im_gray,cmap='gray', vmin = 0, vmax = 255)`

Comment: You don't need to convert the image to single channel `convert("L")` if the only thing you need is to show the image as gray `cmap="gray"` is what you need in `imshow`. I have similar example in OpenCV for [single channel image](https://programming-review.com/python/opencv-create-image#show-single-channel-image), but you can open any RGB image and show it with `cmap='gray'`.

Answer (score 43):

Try to use a grayscale colormap?

E.g. something like

```
imshow(..., cmap=pyplot.cm.binary)
```

For a list of colormaps, see http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.org/items/Matplotlib_Show_colormaps.html

Answer (score 29):

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

You can also run once in your code

```
plt.gray()
```

This will show the images in grayscale as default

```python
im = array(Image.open('I_am_batman.jpg').convert('L'))
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which library are you using for `gray()` or `grey()` ?

Comment: @SherylHohman, it is `gray`... gray is standard American spelling and grey is British spelling for the same color.

Comment: Looking for that, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 18):

I would use the get_cmap method. Ex.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.imshow(matrix, cmap=plt.get_cmap('gray'))
```

Answer (score 15):

@unutbu's answer is quite close to the right answer.

By default, plt.imshow() will try to scale your (MxN) array data to 0.0~1.0. And then map to 0~255. For most natural taken images, this is fine, you won't see a different. But if you have narrow range of pixel value image, say the min pixel is 156 and the max pixel is 234. The gray image will looks totally wrong.
The right way to show an image in gray is

```
from matplotlib.colors import NoNorm
...
plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray',norm=NoNorm())
...
```

Let's see an example:

this is the origianl image:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcXpB.jpg)

this is using defaul norm setting,which is None:
[wrong pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOKgA.png)

this is using NoNorm setting,which is NoNorm():
[right pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWM2a.png)

Comment: In Colab I get error when using `NoNorm`, however `norm=None` works

Answer (score 10):

try this:

```
import pylab
from scipy import misc

pylab.imshow(misc.lena(),cmap=pylab.gray())
pylab.show()
```

Comment: there is no `pylab.grey()`, maybe it has been removed?

Answer (score 9):

Use no interpolation and set to gray.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(img[:,:,1], cmap='gray',interpolation='none')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
plt.imshow(img[:,:,0], cmap='gray')

plt.imshow(img[:,:,1], cmap='gray')

plt.imshow(img[:,:,2], cmap='gray')
```

should work. But, the issue with this approach is that it is not true gray. It only changes one of RGB channel to gray.

look below.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_sample_image
flower = load_sample_image("flower.jpg")

plt.subplot(1,4,1)
plt.imshow(flower)
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("Original")

# R level to gray
plt.subplot(1,4,2)
plt.imshow(flower[:,:,0], cmap='gray')
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("R to gray")


# G leval to gray
plt.subplot(1,4,3)
plt.imshow(flower[:,:,1], cmap='gray')
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("R to gray")

# B leval to gray
plt.subplot(1,4,4)
plt.imshow(flower[:,:,2], cmap='gray')
plt.axis("off")
plt.title("R to gray")

plt.show()
```

[[Result images]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z54w9.png)

Answer (score 1):

When the image has purple & yellow color.

change way of saving image:
`plt.imsave(...., cmap='gray')`