# to print a gray scale image if i have the matrix of intensities in python

Tags: python, image, printing, matrix

```
a=[[22,10,21,22,15,16],
   [24,21,13,20,14,17],
   [23,17,38,23,17,16],
   [25,25,22,14,15,21],
   [27,22,12,11,21,20],
   [24,21,10,12,22,23]
   ]
```

Consider this list of lists as a two dimensional array and can anyone help me how to print this matrix in the form of an image in python.

Comment: This must be related to what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a library such as the [Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (a fork of the Python Image Library).

Have a look at the [Image.frombuffer](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombuffer) function which allows you to build a image from raw pixel data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at pygame. It is a really handy module that comes in use all the time.

Here is a sample code that works:

```
import pygame

a=[[22,10,21,22,15,16],
   [24,21,13,20,14,17],
   [23,17,38,23,17,16],
   [25,25,22,14,15,21],
   [27,22,12,11,21,20],
   [24,21,10,12,22,23]]

BLOCKSIZE = 16
WIDTH = len(a[0]) * BLOCKSIZE
HEIGHT = len(a) * BLOCKSIZE
DISPLAY = (WIDTH, HEIGHT)

WHITE = (255.0,255.0,255.0)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY,0,32)

x = y = 0

for row in a:
    for item in row:
        screen.fill((WHITE[0]*item/50,WHITE[1]*item/50,WHITE[2]*item/50),(x,y,BLOCKSIZE,BLOCKSIZE))
        y += BLOCKSIZE
    x += BLOCKSIZE
    y = 0

pygame.display.update()

while 1:
    pass
```

What this code does is it looks at the value then converts it to a grey color corresponding to its value (0 is black and 50 is white). It then draws it on the screen.

AGAIN, read up on pygame. It is REALLY useful