# Greyscale in python - incorect colors changing from dark grey to light grey to dark grey

Tags: image, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, grayscale

I am plotting a greyscale version of this image:
[image: a busy cat]

SOURCE: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html

I have used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from PIL import Image

file_name = 'griddata_demo.png'
def func_grey(fname):
    image = Image.open(fname).convert("L")
    arr = np.asarray(image)
    plt.imshow(arr, cmap = cm.Greys_r)
    plt.show()

func_grey(file_name)
```

[Display image as grayscale using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib/3823822#3823822)

The setup I am working is has python 2.7 and Pandas and I have installed Pillow with easy install.

Background information about the image and the requirements:

1. The image come from data found [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html). Ideally, the greyscale
   version of this image should be generated directly from this raw
   data.i.e. do not save it as a colored image and then try to convert
   to greyscale - rather just produce a greyscale version of the plot.
2. I do not know the colors that correspond to the z-values - these
   colors can be set arbitrarily.
3. The color map of the image can also be chosen arbitrarily - there is no preference. It 
   is the greyscale version that is of concern.

My question is related to the color scheme shown in the colorbar. I need to display a color scheme where the color bar has colors from light grey (lowest intensity) to dark grey (highest intensity).

After running the above code, a greyscale image is produced. In the color bar of the greyscale image, the intensity level -0.36 is dark grey. At 0.00, it is light grey. But then 0.48 is also dark grey.

Question:
Is is possible to change the colormap such that -0.36 is light grey and 0.48 is dark grey? I mean, is it possible to display to colorbar from light to dark?

Comment: This is a well known problem with the colormap of the original image: that is, that it doesn't have monotonic brightness (in your case, the green at `0` is brighter than either the red or the blue at the extremes.. you can just see it, so don't blame your converter). So instead of converting using brightness, you need to invert the original colormap.  Or, if you can do the color image from scratch and don't need to do an existing image, choose a different colormap, such as `hot`, or cubehelix, etc.

Comment: @tom10: Thanks. I am actually looking into your first reply. I will also read up on your second comment, based on the link, and post back here once I've tried it out.

Comment: The main question would be, what is your original colormap?  Since the above is just a demo, and the colormap details are crucial (in that some are trivial and some are difficult) it's important to know from the outset.

Comment: @tom10: (If you think it would be appropriate to discuss this further on chat, please let me know - I would then post here the results of that, in order to answer the original post.) So, I checked my colormap with "print cm.get_cmap()" and I got "<matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap object at 0x0000000006D81DD8>". It appears that I need to go with the colormap gray which is in the list of Sequential2 colormaps. How could I change the category and select one map from the new category's list?

Comment: Chat is fine with me, though I don't know how to get there, so please initiate that if you do.  It's important to be clear when talking about this problem, what's your original colormap, vs your destination.  Whatever it is please be more clear about the **original image** that you need to convert: 1) do you have any control over it (like can you choose it's colormap)?, do you know what colors correspond to what values and how do you know it?, etc.

Comment: Hi, regarding chat: unfortunately, I cannot chat since I do not have the necessary reputation points. With that in mind, I have updated the original post to provide more information. As you requested, I do not know the colors that correspond to the values - these can be set arbitrarily. Yes, I can choose its color map. The only interest is in the color scheme of the greyscale version image - that is where the emphasis lies.

Comment: So if you can choose the colormap of the original, just choose one that converts to grayscale easily (`hot`, `cubehelix`, etc).  Then `convert(L)` will work and the whole problem is very easy.  Right?  I'll write a quick demo later (if someone else doesn't first).

Comment: @tom10: if you could post a reply, that would be great. I inserted this line "c_map = plt.set_cmap('cubehelix')" before the first line of my function above. But, this does not appear to be changing the image.

Comment: One more thing confuses me: if you can make the original contour plot in any colormap you want, then why not do one in grayscale along with the original (ie, both plots from matplotlib).  I want to be sure that you're not just asking how to change the colormap to grayscale in matplotlib; or do you really need to do image processing on a previously generated contour plot?

Comment: Sorry I should have said that. Yes, I can just do one in grayscale, as you had suggested with both of them coming from matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this question may be about how to use a grayscale colormap in matplotlib.  If so, then it's straightforward.  Here's an example using different colormaps (based on the code for the op image):

[image]

```
from numpy.random import uniform, seed
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
# make up data.
#npts = int(raw_input('enter # of random points to plot:'))

def f(spi, the_colormap):
    plt.subplot(spi)
    seed(0)
    npts = 200
    x = uniform(-2, 2, npts)
    y = uniform(-2, 2, npts)
    z = x*np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)
    xi = np.linspace(-2.1, 2.1, 100)
    yi = np.linspace(-2.1, 2.1, 200)
    zi = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

    CS = plt.contour(xi, yi, zi, 15, linewidths=0.5, colors='k')
    CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 15, cmap=the_colormap,
                      vmax=abs(zi).max(), vmin=-abs(zi).max())
    plt.colorbar()  # draw colorbar
    # plot data points.
    plt.scatter(x, y, marker='o', c='b', s=5, zorder=10)
    plt.xlim(-2, 2)
    plt.ylim(-2, 2)
    plt.title('griddata test (%d points)' % npts)

f(131, plt.cm.rainbow)
f(132, plt.cm.gray)
f(133, plt.cm.hot)

plt.show()
```

If one actually wants to convert to grayscale using PIL (a far less favorable, but sometimes necessary task), it's best to start with a colormap that has monotonic brightness, like `hot` above, but not `rainbow`.  Also, in the comments I suggested using `cubehelix` but that's not standard with matplotlib, instead see [here](http://www.ifweassume.com/2014/04/cubehelix-colormap-for-python.html).  See [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) for an image of the available matplotlib colormaps.

Comment: Yes, this answers the question. I will update the original question to reflect more appropriate wording. Basically, exactly as you said, there is no need to produce the image and save it, then import it simply to change the colormap. This should all be done from the raw data directly. Thanks for your patience and for the reply. This is the answer that I had a lot of trouble finding from online searches.

Comment: Just a followup about your third subplot - you used "hot" as the colormap. I assume that, by default, it chose red - is it possible to set that to other colors?

Comment: I've add in a link where you can see all the included colormaps.  You can also construct your own from scratch pretty easily if they're simple (like hot is), and if you want to do that, search around for linearsegmentedcolormap, but the included ones are probably the way to go now.  (But for your specific question, afaik, you can't change 'hot' to use a different color.)

Comment: Thanks again. All questions in the full post and are answered.

Answer (score 1):

this solution works for me, and is a lot simpler

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.png")
im.convert('L').show()
im.convert('L').save("image.png")
```

note that if you want to mix up the file types, you can (.png to .jpg for example)