# Why does pyplot display wrong grayscale image?

Tags: image, matplotlib

I have a grayscale image:

[image]

But `plt.inshow` displays a wrong image (clearly, it differs from the origin one):

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
img = Image.open('...')
plt.imshow(image, cmap=cm.gray)
```

the output is

[image]

I tried the `img.show()` method, and it can display the same image as the origin one.

My question is: how to display grayscale image correctly using `pyplot`?

I have tried [Display image as grayscale using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib), but it dose not work still.

Answer (score 7):

`imshow` will by default stretch and normalise the data so the minimum value becomes black and the maximum becomes white. You data currently is within the range 90 to 138, so it will map `90->black` and `138->white`.

To prevent this happening, you can give `imshow` the real min and max; in this case I think you want to set `vmin=0, vmax=255`. Try this:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.gray, vmin=0, vmax=255)
```

For me that reproduces your original image.