# the format change during reading images and showing it again on the screen

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, scikit-image

I have a tif images, its type is `float32`, shape is `(128*128)` (a grayscale image). All the pixel values are of range `[0.0, 1.0]`

When I read it using `skimage` and output it using `matplotlib`. The output image looks like a RGB image.

[image]

```
from skimage import io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
output=io.imread(os.path.join(image_path,raw_image_name))
print(output.dtype)
print(output.shape)
print(output.max())
print(output.min())
plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

However, when I read the image using `matplotlib` instead,   `output=plt.imread(os.path.join(image_path,raw_image_name))`. I found that pixel value will become 255 and 0. The output image will become black as shown in the second image. I am confused how does this work? My guess is that there are some dtype change happening during the reading process.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you display images read with `skimage` with `matplotlib` just give it `cmap='gray'` like so:

```
plt.imshow(output,cmap='gray')
```

This should give you a grayscale image of your data. Also check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib).

When you read in tif images using Matplotlib it will try to convert things to a range 0...255, because it falls back to PIL to handle tiffs, which only works with uint8 values according to [the docs](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.0/users/image_tutorial.html):

> As a side note, the only datatype that PIL can work with is uint8. Matplotlib plotting can handle float32 and uint8, but image reading/writing for any format other than PNG is limited to uint8 data.

Comment: Thanks. So if an image was saved as tif, or any other files with types instead of unit8, it is not right to read it using matplotlib. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I think most tif images will be saved as uint8 or similar, at least  when it comes to microscopy imaging data I don't think I've every encountered a tif file with values between 0 and 1. So yes, if you would like to read in data that's not uint8 don't use matplotlib, I'm not sure how it performs on uint16/uint32.