# misc.imshow() doesn't work as expected

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, python-imaging-library

I want to show image in black-white mode in my notebook using scipy's misc.imshow(), however it doesn't work right.

[Here you can see expected picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwubD.jpg)

[And here is what misc.imshow() shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGdn5.png)

What is the problem?

P.S. I use Python 2.7, Pillow (4.1.1), scipy (0.19.0)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib