# Rendering grayscale image

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, grayscale

Using this code :

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 

plt.imshow(cv2.imread('badger.jpeg' , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

an image is read as greyscale and plotted to screen.

The image is plotted as :

[image]

This does not appear to be grayscale as there is colour that does not range form white to grey contained in the rendered image ?

My code is correct to read the image as grayscale using the `IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` parameter ?

The image is located at : https://sciencing.com/difference-between-badger-wolverine-8645505.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display image as grayscale using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image is indeed flattened to grayscale if you use `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE` (you can test this using `cv2.imread('im.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE).shape` and `cv2.imread('im.jpg').shape`, and see that the former is a 3-d array and the latter is a 2-d array)

The issue is with the way `matplotlib` chooses to map your pixel values. When using `plt.imshow()`, it is using the default colormap ([which is `viridis`](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colormap), for some reason). This means pixel intensities / values will be mapped to the following:

[image]

You can change `cmap` to `gray`, in order to map them to the following:

[image]

```
plt.imshow(cv2.imread('badger.jpeg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE), cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

[image]