# opencv convert image to grayscale, and display using matplotlib gives strange color

Tags: opencv, matplotlib

I see an oddness when loading an image using opencv, convert to grayscale, and plot using matplotlib:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import argparse
import cv2

image = cv2.imread("images/image1.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
plt.imshow(image)
```

Just that simple.

But it gives a "grayscale" plot as follows:

Anything wrong ? Many thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because of the way Matplotlib maps single-channel output. It defaults to the "**perceptially uniform**" colourmap: blue->yellow; a bit like how you might expect a heatmap to be from blue to red, but theoretically clearer for human vision.

There's some more details here that might help:
https://matplotlib.org/users/colormaps.html

You need to tell it to use the gray colourmap when you show the image:

```
plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')
```

Also see this question: [Display image as grayscale using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib)

**Edit:** Also, see [lightalchemist's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52334050/168735) answer regarding mixing up RGB and BGR!

Comment: Wasn't aware we can link directly to an answer :).

Comment: Very informative. Many thanks !

Answer (score 7):

OpenCV reads in images in the order BGR so you should convert

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Secondly, what you are seeing is Matplotlib displaying the image intensities as a heatmap. Just pass the desired color map to its `cmap` argument

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

Comment: Good spot on the BGR vs. RGB - I was too focused on the colourmap and didn't even notice that!

Comment: Good point ! Many thanks