# RGb to gray conversion in CV2

Tags: python, rgb, opencv, grayscale

I am trying to convert an image from RGB to grayscale. My image looks like this after reading

```
img = cv2.imread('sample.png')
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image]

I tried converting this to grayscale using cv2 function and the image looks as below after conversion:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.imshow(gray)
```

[image]

As you can see image is not converted to grayscale properly. What could be the reason? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you please try `cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY` instead of `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`. Maybe the order of the colors is not `BGR`.

Comment: @mosc9575 I have already tried that, but no luck. I end up with the same image.

Comment: Duplicate: [opencv convert image to grayscale, and display using matplotlib gives strange color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52333972/opencv-convert-image-to-grayscale-and-display-using-matplotlib-gives-strange-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default option for cmap in `plt.imshow` is `viridis`. Use `plt.imshow(gray, cmap='gray')` for grayscale images. If you save the image using `cv2.imwrite` you can see the image has been converted to grayscale.

Comment: when I save an image with `cv2.imwrite`, and read again using `cv2.imread` I see that the image has three channels. How can I store the gray images with 1 channel?

Comment: `cv2.imread(path, flag)` , set flag to `cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE`