# Determine division line in text using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to detect the division line in the scanned document, and instead of using `cv2.Canny`, I used `cv2.threshold` to get a pretty clean pre-processed image. However my parameter for `cv2.HoughLines` may be improper and I got a chaos in the final output. And the lines didn`t present as the set color.

My code is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

## (1) read
img = cv2.imread("q11.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
plt.figure(figsize=(17,17))
plt.imshow(gray,cmap='gray')

## (2) threshold
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 20, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.imshow(threshed,cmap='gray')

## (3) HoughLines
lines = cv2.HoughLines(threshed,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180,threshold = 800)
for i in range(len(lines)):
    for rho,theta in lines[i]:
        a = np.cos(theta)
        b = np.sin(theta)
        x0 = a*rho
        y0 = b*rho
        x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
        y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
        x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
        y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(threshed,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.subplot(111),plt.imshow(threshed)
plt.title('hough'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
```

The original pic is:
[image]

and after `cv2.threshold` with `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU` I got:
[image]

I want to have:
[image]

What I actually got:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322630/how-to-detect-lines-in-opencv

Comment: As far as your yellow and purple output is concerned, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach

- Convert image to grayscale and gaussian blur
- Threshold image
- Dilate to enhance contour
- Detect lines

---

Threshold

[image]

Next we dilate to enhance contours then use [`cv2.HoughLinesP()`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to detect lines. You mention

> The lines don`t show as the set color

This is because you tried to draw the line on a binary image (the thresholded image). Since it only has one channel, pixels are only white or black. Thus it will not display the color. You have to draw it on a colored image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)

thresh = cv2.threshold(blur,190, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 200
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(dilate,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),3)

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.waitKey()
```