# Inverted / Distorted colors while for single channel images?

Tags: python, scipy

I imported a single channel image (from a `.mat`) file. When I use `plt.imshow()` for the image, the image looks distorted...kind of like inverted hues? Not sure. I think it's something trivial, but I'm unable to understand what exactly is happening. Some have suggested changing from BGR to RGB but that would be valid for RGB images, not single channel ones.

example of how i'm loading my image file -

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy.io import loadmat

red=sp.io.loadmat('red.mat')['red']
```

`red` is a dictionary from which i extract the value of the key `red` whose value is essentially the color intensity matrix.

```
plt.imshow(red)
```

yields [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP0ip.jpg).

funny thing is that red, blue and the green channels they all have the same colour hues. What am I missing?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide us with the original image to compare?

Comment: The original image is a .mat file (array) ..I don't have the original 'red' image. Just the RGB version of it.

Comment: You only want to show the red channel, right?

Comment: Yes, I understand I can do that if I have the original RGB image, but here I am just importing an array which is supposedly just the channel red. So essentially I'm just importing the red channel and using plt.imshow() but I end up getting this weird color map.

Comment: you could try creating a full RGB image, but making the G and B values 0

Comment: i dont think that should be required, i mean that might work - afaik its supposed to be a simple load and show

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199096/discussion-between-axiumin-and-aditya-das).

Answer (score 0):

Imshow is probably using a default colormap.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html

(indeed the documentation points to a default called "viridis")

Use the 'cmap' parameter to specify a colormap (see the list in the following link).

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html

Answer (score 0):

This has thrown me off in the past! From one of the [tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/introductory/images.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-images-py) on the matplotlib documentation:

> Now, with a luminosity (2D, no color) image, the default colormap (aka
> lookup table, LUT), is applied. The default is called viridis. There
> are plenty of others to choose from.
> `plt.imshow(red, cmap="hot")`

So, for any single-channel image, the default false color colormap is utilized, instead of showing as greyscale.

Comment: ugh, okay I see. I did glance over that, but is there anyway to know the best color map?

Comment: What is the purpose of the visualization? Maybe force grayscale? There is some discussion here of how/why to choose a colormap: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html Grayscale: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib

Comment: I just want to check if I imported my data correctly. All I need to do is import three color channels and do a simple color alignment :) I dont need it to be grayscale, I just want it to be red.  Since I imported red.

Comment: OK, there is a "reds" colormap or maybe the "gist_heat" depending on if you want a level of 0 to be white or black. `plt.imshow(red, cmap='reds', vmin=0, vmax=255)

Comment: no there isn't a reds colormap, it says its not recognized. Doing it this way obviously isn't the solution. There must be an easier way. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that is probably my fault! The color map is "Reds" with a capital R