# Specify grid color

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, grid

I am trying to create a grid with gray, white and black colors and specify these colors for each box in the grid.  I could create a grid with 2 rows and three columns, but not sure to specify the colors in the grid (not randomly color the boxes in the grid)

Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Make a 2x3 grid...
nrows, ncols = 2,3
image = np.zeros(nrows*ncols)
image = image.reshape((nrows, ncols))
row_labels = ["Attractor1", "Attractor2"]
col_labels = ['BCL6', 'GRIN2A', 'PAFAH1B1']
plt.matshow(image)
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels)
plt.show()
```

This is how I want to create the grid figure

[image]

I also tried this code below. But, I don't how to specify the color for gray and change the lables

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = [[0,1],[1,0]]
plt.imshow(a,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is not working with what you have done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display image as grayscale using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823752/display-image-as-grayscale-using-matplotlib)

Comment: How to specify colors in the grid? For example as shown in the figure. Some blocks are in black, some boxes are in white and gray. How to give it in a code, the color for each box in the grid?

Comment: @JodyKlymak No, in this link, a image is imported and the colors are displayed on grayscale. Thanks

Comment: Fill your matrix with 0, 0.5, and 1?

Comment: When I give as 0 and 1, I can get the colors black and white. How to do it for gray color? I have pasted the code at the end of the question. Please find it

Comment: If black is 0, white is 1, then grey is ???

Comment: Yes, Thanks I can get the grey color if i give 0.5. I will edit the code above for answer

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code to plot a grid, specify the colors for each box in the grid as well specify the row and column names

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = [[0,1,0.5],[1,0,0.5]]
nrows, ncols = 2,3
image = np.zeros(nrows*ncols)
image = image.reshape((nrows, ncols))
row_labels = ["Attractor1", "Attractor2"]
col_labels = ['BCL6', 'GRIN2A', 'PAFAH1B1']
plt.matshow(image)
plt.xticks(range(ncols), col_labels)
plt.yticks(range(nrows), row_labels)
plt.imshow(a,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```